# My ex employer wants me to draft my own reference letter to the MSc program, is it unethical?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I submitted my application for a MSc program and one of my referees was declined this week by the department. Because this was so sudden from the department and I had to find someone who is willing to write me a reference letter in 3 days notice, I asked my previous employer to write me one.
My employer told me to simply draft my own letter and send it back to him so he can upload it !

is it unethical? the rejection of my initial referee was sudden and none of my old professors would remotely agree to write me a letter in two days notice. I don't want to commit anything wrong that could compromise my candidancy.

Answer (score 10):

No, it is not. Your employer will get the letter and "tweak" it. When he uploads that letter, it means that he agrees with its content.

I had seen multiple professors do this to some colleagues of mine and there is nothing unethical about it.

Comment: The accepted answer on the dupe says _"No, this is a form of plagiarism and academic fraud. What you pass off as your written word must actually be yours except where you explicitly document to the contrary."_ I'm in agreement with that assessment. I'm stunned to see this answer being given 7 upvotes.

Comment: _"I'm stunned to see this answer being given 7 upvotes"_ Some people are just better at accepting reality. Also, that question has another answer voted equality high expressing the exact other opinion.